# how ssl works in web development?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

This question may seem stupid, but this has been bothering me for a long while.

So I understand that a website using SSL socket (https?) will encrypt the transmission.

My problem is, does it only encrypt the data (get/post fields?), or the entire page (that would be super slow i guess).

If it's encypted, say I'm using php as the backend, how do I handle the encrypted data? Or would the entire development be as usual as like it was a normal website. Except some additional works need to be done on the server?

I'm currently encrypting some essential data (password, credit card) using RSA library (js and php) when sending requests to server. But, it is really slow (or it was because I used a 1024 bit encryption?).

And now I'm tasked to develop interface for an online payment API, which requires SSL secured site. So I'm wondering how does SSL impact the site in terms of developing process.

TYIA

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Or maybe [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) for you security design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is, does it only encrypt the data (get/post fields?)

Yes.

> or the entire page

Yes. There is no difference between this question and the previous one. SSL encrypts the entire request and response. Everything that is sent over over the wire.

> (that would be super slow i guess).

No. I have experimental data that shows it is no worse than three times as slow as plaintext over the Internet.

> If it's encrypted, say I'm using php as the backend, how do I handle the encrypted data?

You *don't* 'handle the encrypted data' in any way. SSL encrypts and decrypts it for you. You just handle plaintext.

> Or would the entire development be as usual as like it was a normal website.

Yes.

> Except some additional works need to be done on the server?

Except for defining the relevant pages as requiring SSL, and installing an SSL certificate.

> I'm currently encrypting some essential data (password, credit card) using RSA library (js and php) when sending requests to server. But, it is really slow (or it was because I used a 1024 bit encryption?).

Yes and yes. Use SSL.

> And now I'm tasked to develop interface for an online payment API, which requires SSL secured site. So I'm wondering how does SSL impact the site in terms of developing process.

Considerably less than what you're already doing.